# How to retrieve /echo the value of an $_GET array

Tags: php, arrays

This might be very easy for some, however I do not seem to be able to retrieve my value that is send via a GET method

Here is what I've got:

```
mypage.php?Goods[0][Description]=Dining table
```

How do I manage to echo out The Goods?

I have tried the following

```
$Good = $_GET['Goods[0][Description]'];
echo $Good;
```

However it returns the word Array, so I presume that $Goods is an array, but when I tried

```
foreach ($Good as $description){
echo $description}
```

nothing works.
I would like to echo out the value of `Goods[0][Description]`

The `print_r($_GET)` gives me `[Goods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Description] => Dining table` 
Any help welcome
And again sorry if it is a very obvious question

Comment: `print_r($_GET)` and  share output ?

Comment: passing Goods[0][Description]=Dining is bad. First print print_r($_GET), and check what you will get

Comment: `$_GET['Goods'][0]['Description']`

Comment: You can use var_dump($_GET['Goods']); to see exactly what you will get.

Comment: @jeroen That worked, it is echoing out now.  Thanks so much for that

Answer (score 0):

$goods is an array, $good is an array as well, with elements having description key. So, if you'd like to echo out all of $goods' elements descriptions, you should go like this

```
$goods = $_GET['Goods'];

foreach($goods as $good) {
    echo $good['Description'];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't you need a ";" after `echo $description`?